# MariaDB's ORDER BY clause does not sort ascending?

Tags: sorting, mariadb

I have the below simple SQL, which is executed against my MariaDB database.

The expected behavior is that the result is sorted by 'day' **ASCENDING**.  However, when executed, the results are sorted in **DESCENDING** order.  Very strange.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT `day`,`count` 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            DATE(`date`) AS `day`,
            COUNT(*) as `count` 
        FROM `message` m
        GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
        ORDER BY `day` DESC, `count` DESC
    ) AS q 
    ORDER BY `day` ASC
) AS q
```

If I comment out the ORDER BY **inside** the inner query, the outer ORDER BY works correctly and sorts the results in **ascending** order without problem.

The problem I have is that the code inside the inner loop is generated code, so I can't remove that inner ORDER BY.

Why does MariaDB behave in this way?  Is there some way to change the outer ORDER BY so that it gets the priority is deserves?

Note:  I am using MariaDB version:  10.0.24-MariaDB

Comment: Please try something -- Since `count` and `day` are semi-reserved-words, change the spelling of those.

Comment: Thanks Rick James. Unfortunately, whatever I change the names to, the behaviour stays the same.

Comment: I am just now seeing the 'edit' -- You added an extra (unnecessary) layer.  TomG has the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i worked it out.

According to MariaDB, the SQL standard does not require the ORDER BY of a subquery to be respected (unless it would affect the actual rows returned):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

If I move the ORDER BY to the very outside query, then it works as expected.